# Alignment of elements in TabPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, panel, extjs5

How should I manipulate elements inside a TabPanel?

For example on the 1st tab I have two Items - these are charts. However the 2nd item is aligned at the bottom of the 1st item (linechart). How can I align the second item (line chart) on the right side with the first on the left?

Here's the ff code

```
Ext.define('UM.view.main.umcontent',{
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'umcontent',

    height: 400,
    width: 2000,
    tabPosition: 'left',

    tabRotation: 0,
    tabBar: {

        border: true,

    },

    defaults: {
        textAlign: 'left',
        bodyPadding: 15
    },




items: [{
    title: 'Home',
    autoScroll: true,
    items:[{
            xtype: 'OverallCost',

           },

           {
             xtype:'OverallCount'
           }

    ]

}, {
    title: 'Utilization Summary',
    autoScroll: true,
    items:[{

        xtype: 'Overall'
        }]
}, {
    title: 'TOPs'
}, {
    title: ' Cases'
},
{
    title: 'Members Details'

},
{
    title: 'Download Report'
}
]

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options for adjusting the layout

1. Use `layout:'border` in your parent Panel and then specify the region (North, East, South, West, or Center) for each item you want to move.
2. Use `'layout:'absolute'` and then define the x and y coordinates for each item. See the Documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Absolute).
3. Use `layout:'hbox'` which is well defined [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox).

Comment: See Documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border).
Note: This method requires for one item to have `region:'center'` 

Extjs 5 layouts can be demoed and explored more [here](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#layouts)